# OrientDB - exception when I try to save an embeddedlist

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, embeddedlist

I have a class named `CalculationFunctionGroup` where I have an attribute like this:

```
List<CalculationFunction> functions;
```

on my OrientDB I have a table named `CalculationFunctionGroup` with a property `functions` definaed as EMBEDDEDLIST and linked class `CalculationFunction`.

When I try to save an object of type CalculationFunctionGroup an exception raises.

The exception tell me:

> The field 'functions' has been declared as EMBEDDEDLIST with linked class 'CalculationFunction' but the record has no class.

I try to find this exception in OrientDB source code, and I find this:

There's a check in `ODocument` class in the method `validateEmbedded` where there are these code lines:

```
if (doc.getImmutableSchemaClass() == null)
      throw new OValidationException("The field '" + p.getFullName() + "' has been declared as " + p.getType()
          + " with linked class '" + embeddedClass + "' but the record has no class");
```

So, I don't understand how can I valued the immutableschemaclass property.

Where I try to set my field value from Java, I use this command line:

```
this.data.field(fieldName, value, OType.EMBEDDEDLIST);
```

where `data` is my `ODocument` instance, `fieldName` is `functions`, value is my `List` of `CalculationFunction` and `OType` is `EMBEDDEDLIST`.

Used Orient version is 2.2.0

**EDIT #1**

I try this after Alessandro Rota answer, but the error is the same:

```
ODocument myEntity = new ODocument("CalculationFunctionGroup");
myEntity.field("referenceItem", object.getReferenceItem().getData());
db.save(myEntity);
db.commit();
```

In this code snippet I've changed the nature of my objct (the original is a typied object as CalculationFunctionGroup and now is an ODocument). But the error is the same.

Another try I've done, the ODocument `myEntity` has not attached functions (list of CalculationFunction) but the error raises too

**EDIT #2**

I've tried with code snippet of Alessandro Rota and works fine.

But when I add as field of CalculationFunction a link field I've the same error! Why?

If I add a link field instead of object.getData() with object.getRawField("@rid") it works fine too.

I don't understand because raises that error message, and the reason of different behaviour when I use only @rid field instead complete object

**EDIT #3**
Latest news:

This is my test scenario:

I have this table:

CalculationFunction with these property (schemafull):

referenceItem LINK
functions EMBEDDEDLIST

When I try to save, I write this code:

```
    ODocument myGroup = new ODocument("CalculationFunctionGroup");
    Object rid = null;
    if (object.getField("referenceItem") instanceof RegistryMetadata) {
        rid = ((RegistryMetadata)(object.getField("referenceItem"))).getRawField("@rid");
    } else if (object.getField("referenceItem") instanceof PayrollRegistryMetadata) {
        rid = ((PayrollRegistryMetadata)(object.getField("referenceItem"))).getRawField("@rid");
    } else if (object.getField("referenceItem") instanceof PreCalculationMetadata) {
        rid = ((PreCalculationMetadata)(object.getField("referenceItem"))).getRawField("@rid");
    } else if (object.getField("referenceItem") instanceof CalculationMetadata) {
        rid = ((CalculationMetadata)(object.getField("referenceItem"))).getRawField("@rid");
    }

    myGroup.field("referenceItem", rid, OType.LINK);
    myGroup.field("scenario", ((Scenario)object.getField("scenario")).getRawField("@rid"));

    List<ODocument> lstFunctions = new ArrayList<ODocument>();
    if (object.getField("functions") != null) {
        Iterable<ODocument> lstFun = (Iterable<ODocument>) object.getField("functions");
        Iterator<ODocument> itFun = lstFun.iterator(); 
        while(itFun.hasNext()) {
            ODocument currFun = itFun.next();

            ODocument oFun = new ODocument("CalculationFunction");
            oFun.field("name", currFun.field("name"));
            oFun.field("code", currFun.field("code"));
            oFun.field("language", currFun.field("language"));

            lstFunctions.add(oFun);
        }
    }
    myGroup.field("functions", lstFunctions, OType.EMBEDDEDLIST);
    myGroup.save();

    db.commit();
```

This code goes in error, but... If I write this:

```
    myGroup.field("referenceItem2", rid, OType.LINK);
```

The code works fine.

The difference: referenceItem is a schemafull property, referenceItem2 is a schemaless field.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this code

```
ODocument cf1= new ODocument("CalculationFunction");
cf1.field("name","Function 1",OType.STRING);

ODocument cf2= new ODocument("CalculationFunction");
cf2.field("name","Function 2",OType.STRING);

List<ODocument> list=new ArrayList<ODocument>();
list.add(cf1);
list.add(cf2);

ODocument p = new ODocument("CalculationFunctionGroup");
p.field("functions", list, OType.EMBEDDEDLIST);
p.save();
```

[image]

**Edit 2**

If you want add a link you could use this code

```
ODocument cf1= new ODocument("CalculationFunction");
cf1.field("name","Function 1",OType.STRING);

ODocument p = new ODocument("CalculationFunctionGroup");
p.field("mylink", cf1, OType.LINK);
p.save();
```

**EDIT 3**

I have created schemafull property mylink2

[image]

I have used this code

```
ODocument cf1= new ODocument("CalculationFunction");
cf1.field("name","Function 1",OType.STRING);
cf1.save();

ODocument p = new ODocument("CalculationFunctionGroup");
p.field("mylink", cf1.getIdentity(), OType.LINK);
p.field("mylink2", cf1.getIdentity(), OType.LINK);
p.save();
```

and I got

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please check my updated question (after your advice)

Comment: Could you try esactly with my code in a new database to see if it creates all correctly ?

Comment: Dear, I've updated again my question, I hope this further detail can be useful to determine my issue.

Comment: So I can add a link field only as ODocument and no as Object?

Comment: And what's the reason about different behaviour if a field is schemaless or shcemafull?

Comment: If I use getData() method it returns an ODocument but I've the same error. So I suppose your EDIT#2 is not good